# Tap animation on Image SwiftUI

Tags: swift, image, animation, swiftui, gesture

How can I make an animation on an image so when I tap it and hold it scales backwards and when I release it the image return to its original size?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "heart")
        .onTapGesture {
        // Gesture when held down and released
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoImageScale: View {
    @GestureState private var isDetectingPress = false

    var body: some View {
        Image("plant")
            .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .scaleEffect(isDetectingPress ? 0.5 : 1)
            .animation(.spring())
            .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1).sequenced(before:DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0))
                .updating($isDetectingPress) { value, state, _ in
                    switch value {
                        case .second(true, nil):
                            state = true
                        default:
                            break
                    }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I didn't even know that `@GestureState` property wrapper exists. Thanks!

Comment: That works good, the only thing is that it's kinda slow...how can I speed the animation?

Comment: @xmetal Change the animation part, eg. `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))`

Comment: @pawello2222 I just realized that what might be changed here is the LongPressGesture. I tried with TapGesture because I need to see the animation as soon as I tap on the image but I lose the scaleEffect animation if I do so

Comment: @xmetal, TapGesture is momentary so it does not work for you case. Try to tune `LongPressGesture(minDuration: )` as updated, as well as any other modifiers, like mentioned above animation.

Comment: @Asperi I see, I have finally set it as I wanted but the only problem is that when I longpress on it to perform an action, if I drag my finger out of the image and release it, it still perform the action

Comment: @Asperi `...(minDuration:...` is `...(minimumDuration:...`